# How to apply a transformation to a total derivative?

Tags: evaluation, pattern-matching

I want to transform total derivatives into normal derivatives:

```
Dt[r, t] == -r*Dt[v, x] - v*Dt[r, x] /. Dt[f_, s_] :> D[f[x, t], s]
```

To get:

```
D[r[x, t], t] == -r*D[v[x, t], x] - v*D[r[x, t], x]
```

But the replacement rule above doesn't seem to match Dt.

Only the explicit rule, `Dt[v, x] /. Dt[v, x] :> D[v[x], x]` works, but
`Dt[v, x] /. Dt[f_, t_] :> D[f[t], t]` yields `Dt[v, x]`, not `D[v[x],x]`.

Of course, the work-around is just to start with normal derivatives, but I was trying to get a nicely formatted version of the Euler equations which I could then use for further operations like `NDSolve`, and Dt made it much more readable than having explicit functions of x and t for rho, v, and e:

```
Module[
 {u = \[Rho] {1, v, e}, 
  p = (\[Gamma] - 1) \[Rho] (e - 1/2 v^2) /. \[Gamma] -> 3/2,
  F, eqn, deqn,
  dwdt = Dt[{\[Rho], v, e}, t]},
 F = {\[Rho] v, \[Rho] v^2 + p, v (\[Rho] e + p)};
 (*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]u\)+\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]F\)==0*)
 eqn = Thread[Dt[u, t] + Dt[F, x] == 0];
 deqn = Thread[dwdt == (dwdt /. First@Solve[eqn, dwdt])];
 Print@TraditionalForm[TableForm@deqn];
 TableForm[deqn /. {Dt[f_, s_] :> \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(s\)]\(f[x, t]\)\)}]
 ]
```

I've encountered this issue many times when doing mechanics problems. Even something as simple as the equation of motion for a double pendulum is difficult to parse because of all the explicit functions.

I've considered doing the reverse:

```
expressionWithD /. Derivative[ijk__][f_][x_, t_] :> Dt[f,???]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RuleDelayed` (`:>`) doesn't hold its first argument (it only has the attribute `HoldRest`), so your rule will evaluate to:

```
Dt[f_, s_] :> D[f[x, t], s]
(* Dt[f, s_] Derivative[1, 0][Pattern][f, _] :> D[f[x, t], s] *)
```

This is clearly undesired.

To resolve the problem, use `HoldPattern` to stop the automatic evaluation of `Dt[f_, s_]`:

```
Dt[r, t] == -r Dt[v, x] - v Dt[r, x] /. HoldPattern@Dt[f_, s_] :> D[f[x, t], s]
(* Derivative[0, 1][r][x, t] == 
   -v Derivative[1, 0][r][x, t] - r Derivative[1, 0][v][x, t] *)
```